# How to plot the solutions of $f(z,a)=0$ for $z$ in the complex plane?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, color, complex

I have an equation $f(z,a)=0$ where $z$ is a **complex** variable $\frac {56}{10}<z<2\pi$ and $a$ is a **real** variable $0<a<\pi$.

I want to plot solutions of this equation on the complex plane $z$ as $a$ increases from $0$ to $\pi$, and show the behavior of $z$ by changing the color of the curve (as $a$ increases, the curve changes from blue to red), something like this plot

[image]

```
f[z_,a_]:=9 + 4 Cos[a - (273 z)/50] - 4 Cos[a - 2 z] - 2 Cos[2 z] - 
 3 Cos[(173 z)/50] + Cos[4 z] - 2 Cos[(273 z)/50] - 
 3 Cos[(373 z)/50] - 4 Cos[a + 2 z] + 4 Cos[a + (273 z)/50] - 
 4 I Sin[a - (273 z)/50] + 4 I Sin[a - 2 z] - 2 I Sin[2 z] - 
 3 I Sin[(173 z)/50] + I Sin[4 z] - 2 I Sin[(273 z)/50] - 
 3 I Sin[(373 z)/50] - 4 I Sin[a + 2 z] + 4 I Sin[a + (273 z)/50];


f[z,a]==0

56/10 <z<\[Pi]
0<a<\[Pi]
```

Comment: What do you mean by: "z  is a complex variable 56/10<z<2π" This statement makes only sense if z is real. Dou you Arg[z],Abs[z],...?

Answer (score 1):

This question is fundamentally no different than your previous question.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[z_, a_] := 
  9 + 4 Cos[a - (273 z)/50] - 4 Cos[a - 2 z] - 2 Cos[2 z] - 
   3 Cos[(173 z)/50] + Cos[4 z] - 2 Cos[(273 z)/50] - 3 Cos[(373 z)/50] - 
   4 Cos[a + 2 z] + 4 Cos[a + (273 z)/50] - 4 I Sin[a - (273 z)/50] + 
   4 I Sin[a - 2 z] - 2 I Sin[2 z] - 3 I Sin[(173 z)/50] + I Sin[4 z] - 
   2 I Sin[(273 z)/50] - 3 I Sin[(373 z)/50] - 4 I Sin[a + 2 z] + 
   4 I Sin[a + (273 z)/50];
```

Again, following Ulrich Neumann' s recommendation to use [`NMinimize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMinimize.html)

```
sol[a_?NumericQ] := 
 NMinimize[{Abs[f[x + I*y, a]], 56/10 < x < 2 Pi, y < 0}, {x, y}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 20][[2]]

(data = Table[{x, y, a} /. sol[a], {a, 0, Pi, 1/100}];) // Quiet
```

Use [`Interpolation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html) to define `a` as a function of `x` for use in the [`ColorFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html)

```
afx = Interpolation[data[[All, {1, 3}]]];

Legended[
 ListLinePlot[Most /@ data,
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {Re[z], Im[z]}),
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData["Rainbow"][afx[x]/Pi]],
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  PlotLabel -> Style[
    StringForm["`` = 0", HoldForm[f[z, a]]],
    14, Bold],
  Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[4],
    Table[Tooltip[Point[{x, y} /. sol[a]],
      StringForm["a\[ThinSpace]=\[ThinSpace]``", a]], {a, 0, Pi, Pi/4}]}],
 BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, Pi}},
  LegendLabel -> Style[a, 14, Bold]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, is not there any other way rather than using `Interpolation`? Since when I change the domain, Mathematica warns that some points are duplicates.

Comment: Something like using `ContourPlot`?

Comment: Since `a` is not one of the available parameters to `ColorFunction` it must be introduced as a function of one of the available parameters. As shown in previous answers, use [`DeleteDuplicatesBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicatesBy.html).